# Remove particular duplicate in dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I need to populate a dictionary (`[String: Any]`) but I have a problem:

This is an example of my `[Parameters]`:

> [App.WalkedItinerary(time: 3, lat: 10.932175700000002, long: 10.914),
>   App.WalkedItinerary(time: 3, lat: 10.932175700000002, long: 10.914),
>   App.WalkedItinerary(time: 4, lat: 10.932175700000002, long: 10.914),
>   App.WalkedItinerary(time: 5, lat: 10.932175700000002, long: 10.914),
>   App.WalkedItinerary(time: 6, lat: 10.932175700000002, long: 10.914),
>   App.WalkedItinerary(time: 7, lat: 10.932175700000002, long: 10.914),
>   App.WalkedItinerary(time: 8, lat: 10.932175700000002, long: 10.914),
>   App.WalkedItinerary(time: 0, lat: 10.93217575, long: 10.914),
>   App.WalkedItinerary(time: 1, lat: 10.93217575, long: 10.914)]

I need to filter it in that way:
Remove all of the same lat e long object but which have the highest time. So, an example:

> App.WalkedItinerary(time: 8, lat: 10.932175700000002, long: 10.914),
>   App.WalkedItinerary(time: 1, lat: 10.93217575, long: 10.914)]

```
static func fecth(walks:[WalkedItinerary]) -> [Parameters]{
    var dicts:[Parameters] = []
    for walk in walks{
        // {’lat’:10, 'lng’:10, 'time’:1}
        let myDic:Parameters = ["lat" : walk.lat,
                     "lng" : walk.long,
                     "time" : walk.time]
        dicts.append(myDic)

    }

    return dicts
}
```

Comment: `myDic`. Say it aloud a few times and consider changing it.

Comment: lol even though I'm not american I should change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should sort the array descending by time, then append those to `dicts` which are not already inside it.

```
let walksDescByTime = walks.sorted { $0.time > $1.time }
var dicts: [Parameters] = []
var coordsInDicts = [(lat: Double, long: Double)]()

for walk in walksDescByTime {
    let walkCoord = (lat: walk.lat, long: walk.long)

    if !coordsInDicts.contains(walkCoord) {
            coordsInDicts.append(walkCoord)

            let myDict: Parameters = ["lat": walk.lat,
                                      "lng": walk.long,
                                      "time": walk.time]
            dicts.append(myDict)
    }
}
```